# Handling file submissions with html and python

Tags: python, html, django, file-upload

I'm trying to create a form that will handle video file uploads from the user, but I'm running into a bunch of problems. I am trying to avoid building a model form for this because I won't be saving the file to my database long term. I just want to get it to the server so that I can submit it to youtube. The html I have is:

```
<form method='post' action='/new/' enctype="multi-part/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type='file' name='file' id='file'/>
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

and then the view attempts to handle the file like so:

```
def create_video(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video = request.POST['file']

        command=subprocess.Popen('youtube-upload --email=' + email + ' --password=' + password + '--title=' + title + ' --description=' + description + ' --category=Sports ' + video, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        vid = command.stdout.read()

        # do stuff to save video instance to database
        return show_video(request, video.id)
    else:
        form=Video()
    return render_to_response('create_video.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
```

note: youtube-upload is a python module to upload videos to youtube with that given command.

So for starters when I submit the form from the front end django sends a message saying `"Key 'file' not found in <QueryDict:...`

and given that I fix the form so that it will submit properly is the rest of the view properly handling the file?

Comment: I hope you understand the security risks related to what you're doing.

Comment: to be honest I don't. As it stands currently this is just on localhost and I do understand that this will have to be changed in order to not pose a security risk, but I would like to get a basic understanding of the mechanism first. If you have alternative's for how to handle this basic process I'm all ears.

Comment: you should never call system commands with user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.POST` doesn't contain file upload information. You need to use [`request.FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES).

Comment: great thanks, but now I get an error on the `command=subprocess.Popen(youtube-upload --email=email --password=password --title=' + title + ' --description=' + description + ' --category=Sports ' + video, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. I get `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found`. I know the command itself works in terminal.

Comment: @DanLeaningphp, that's because each value in `request.FILES` is an instance of [`UploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.UploadedFile), not a path or anything like that -- in fact the file might not be written to your filesystem yet (a small enough file will be stored in memory). You should read the docs on [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) -- probably you'll want to save the contents of the file to disk somewhere, then run your command, then delete it.