# Looking for a more complete explanation of how to upload video to youtube

Tags: python, html, django, file-upload, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem accessing user uploaded video in temporary memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906935/problem-accessing-user-uploaded-video-in-temporary-memory)

So I've tried this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906935/problem-accessing-user-uploaded-video-in-temporary-memory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893870/handling-file-submissions-with-html-and-python) but I might have been being too specific or misguided in my question.

Essentially I am trying to take a video submitted via `<form> <input type='file'/> </form>` and submit it to youtube.

I've looked at [youtube direct](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/ytdirect.html), but it is a nightmare to setup and doesn't really provide the functionality I'm looking for. I've looked at the youtube data api but as stated in the previous question the docs are somewhat lacking in specificity regarding implementation in python.

If anyone could walk me through this or point me in the direction of a great tutorial I would be forever grateful.

My previous questions pretty well outline what I am currently trying but here it is for quick reference:

html:

```
<form method='post' action='/new/' enctype="multi-part/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<input type='file' name='file' id='file'/>
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

django view (youtube-upload is a python module that uses the youtube data api to upload a file to youtube using the information specified):

```
 def upload_video(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         video = request.FILE['file']
         v = video.temporary_file_path
         command = 'youtube-upload --email=email@gmail.com --password=password --title=title --description=description --category=Sports ' + v   

         r=subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

         vid = r.stdout.read()
     else:
         form = VideoForm()
         request.upload_handlers.pop(0)
     return render_to_response('create_check.html', RequestContext(request, locals() ) )
```

currently `v=video.temporary_file_path draws` the error `'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'temporary_file_path'`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If `youtube-upload` is a Python module, what possible reason could you have for executing it from the command line instead of `import`ing it?

Comment: Also, the comments on your other questions (which you should have UPDATED, not posted again with slight variations) say that you need to save the file to your filesystem before trying to upload it, as smaller files will be stored in memory, and so _don't have a_ `temporary_file_path`. Why post a new question if you didn't do this?

Comment: I totally understand your criticism, let me try and explain.  Module possibly isn't the right descriptor, youtube upload can be found here http://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload/wiki/Readme . I did update my old question but hadn't gotten any responses.  Shortly after posting this question I learned about bounties so I completely understand if this question is voted to be closed (although I would obviously prefer that it was answered).  In my previous question I tried to explain that I didn't understand the answer submitted. Again sorry for any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem is that your file hasn't been saved to disk, so how could it have a path?

There are two obvious solutions. First, you can change your [FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS) to have only one handler, like so:

```
("django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",)
```

so it will automatically save all files to disk.

Second, you could save the file manually by doing

```
with open('some/file/name', 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in video.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

and then just pass `some/file/name` in the arguments to `youtube_upload.main_upload`.

If you had **read the Django Docs** which answers to **both** of your first two questions pointed you to, you would know this.

The [source of Youtube Upload](http://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload/source/browse/trunk/youtube_upload/youtube_upload.py) makes it clear it can certainly be imported. Simply `import youtube_upload` with it in your path and then call it with `youtube_upload.main_upload(arguments, output)` where `arguments` is

```
['--email=email@gmail.com', '--password=password', '--title=title', '--description=description', '--category=Sports', 'path/to/file']
```

The `output` option defaults to `sys.stdout`, you can redirect it if you need it.

Comment: Now that I've finally gotten this figured out I agree that this question should probably be deleted as the elements of your answer that ended up working for me are covered in my other questions.